# Get values from Struts 2 to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp, struts2

My aim is to display values on button click in JSP page. Control returned to `$http.get("angularAction.action").success(
                        function(data)` , but in console value is displayed as `null`

**Action**

```
private LoginModel personData=new LoginModel();
private JSONObject jSONObject;

public String returnDetails(){

    System.out.println("in returnDetails");
    personData.setFirstName("James");
    personData.setLastName("John");
    jSONObject=new JSONObject();
    jSONObject.put("result",personData);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**XML**

```
<action name="angularAction" class="com.scrolls.AjsStruts.login.action.LoginAction" method="returnDetails">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="root">jSONObject</param>
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
                <param name="noCache">true</param>
            </result>
    </action>
```

**JSP**

```
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>AjsStruts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
            $http.get("angularAction.action").success(
                    function(data) {
                            console.log(data.result);
                            $scope.person = data.result;
                    }).error(function(data) {
                                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                    // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
    };
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Get Data</h1>
    <div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
            <button data-ng-click="getDataFromServer()">
            Fetch data from server
            </button>
            <p>First Name : {{person.firstName}}</p>
            <p>Last Name : {{person.lastName}}</p>
            {{person}}
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Rename `jSONObject` to some name which doesn't start with a single lower case letter.

Comment: i have changed 'jSONObject' to 'result' but there is no change

Comment: Try to print `data` into console.

Comment: Use `toString()` before returning result code.

Comment: I have changed  "jSONObject.put("result",personData);" to  "jSONObject.put("result",personData.toString());", then also value in console is null

Comment: @Asha You  didn't serialize JSON object with this code and it's wrong.

Comment: how to correct that?

Comment: You still didn't change the naming of `jSONObject`.

Comment: @Asha Before returning a result you need to serialize you object to json or use an object that is serializable.

Comment: I have changed that, now my action is :                                                     private String user;
    private LoginModel personData=new LoginModel();
    public String returnDetails(){
        
        System.out.println("in returnDetails");
        personData.setFirstName("James");
        personData.setLastName("John");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

Comment: @Asha Post the code for `LoginModel` and action class.

Comment: And in action configuration? [Edit] your post.

Comment: I got the value in JSP. Problem is that, getter and setter methods of "personData" was not created in Action. And there is no need of JSONObject. Thank you for all answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems are there in three pages , Corrected code is

**Action**

```
 public String returnDetails(){
    personData.setFirstName("James");
    personData.setLastName("John");
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Getters and setters of personData need to be created

**XML**

```
  <action name="angularAction"  class="com.scrolls.AjsStruts.login.action.LoginAction" method="returnDetails">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="root">personData</param>
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
                <param name="noCache">true</param>
            </result>
    </action>
```

**JSP**

```
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
            $http.get("angularAction.action").success(
                    function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                            $scope.person = response.data;
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                    // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
    };
    };
    </script>
```